# Overflow: hidden conundrum on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have 2 bootstrap navbars immediately followed by 2 horizontally centered dropdown menus as follows...

```
<div class="bodyWrapper"> 

  <!-- top navbar - doesn't change size-->
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse nav-top">
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- bottom navbar - collapses and changes size-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" >
    ...
  </nav>    

  <!-- 2 dropdown menus, always centered, and underneath the navbars-->
  <div style="width: 100%;">
      <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; top: -20px;">
              <nav id="menu" class="menu"> 
              </nav>
              <nav id="menu2" class="menu"> 
              </nav>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

With just this setup, a horizontal scroll bar appears on mobile devices allowing the user to scroll across to nothing but blank space, other than my top navbar (which for some reason continues to fill the whole screen).  I don't know why this happens but to solve it, I can add this CSS...

```
.bodyWrapper {
  position : relative; 
  overflow : hidden;
}
```

(I experimented first applying overflow/overflow-x:hidden properties to body/html but it didn't remove the scroll bar on my iPhone).

But the problem with this option is that since the dropdown menus are now inside a wrapper with overflow:hidden, when the user tries to expand them they're cut off.

The only solution I can come up with, it to take the dropdown menus outside of the bodyWrapper div and use absolute positioning on them - but this is a pretty bad option since I'd constantly have to readjust their positioning because the height of the navbars above them can grow.

Anyway, all that's a long way of asking whether anyone can see a better way to deal with this mobile-specific (at least iPhones) issue.  Thanks for any thoughts at all!

---

### EDIT

example as requested:
http://codepen.io/d3wannabe/pen/gaVXzO
(the last line of the css can be commented in/out to see what happens to the dropdown)

Comment: Can you make fiddle ?

Comment: What is your [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable = yes">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set display of dropdown class to inline-block and its parent to have text-align to center.

```
.dropdown{
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

Check out here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aveEoP

Comment: thanks zan - I'm really sorry, but in simplifiying the codepen I think I understated the importance of the div "<div style="position: relative; left: 50%; ">" - that's needed because in my site I have 2 dropdown menus that need to be centered in combination, so I can't rely on just text-align: center to do the job.  That's the essence of the problem really - my solution for centering a div with 2 objects creates an overflow which I can't get rid of without cutting off the dropdowns!  Any other thoughts would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: even 2 drop downs would work fine when we have text-align center

Comment: thanks zan - you're completely right!  I was seeing different behaviour on my live site since I had a second issue where the dropdowns were falling outside of their parent divs, but you've completely solved the problem so I'm marking this as the answer.  Thanks again!